# What mechanic prevents Desolator and Mask of Madness from stacking?

Tags: dota-2

One person from the other team (hero-sniper) was having a bad game. After about 30-40 minutes, someone noticed his build; it was Desolator and Mask of Madness. My friends started to laugh at him and make fun. I joined them to laugh but a question remained in my mind.

**What is it that keeps Desolator and Mask of Madness from stacking?**

Comment: They don't stack because they don't stack. If you want to know why the devs decided they shouldn't stack, that's off topic

Comment: [Meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11319/3062) about whether or not this should be on-topic:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because both are [unique attack modifiers](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Unique_Attack_Modifier) so they won't stack.

You are basically giving up their main purpose (either the armor reduction or life steal depending on which item is older).

You can still get the benefit of the passive and activation ability but those are not nearly as cost effective.

Comment: It is worth noting that you can switch between your item modifiers by dropping the item you do NOT want active and immediately picking it back up. This is only very rarely a good idea, for example when using Desolator for a single shot against a target (eg: a Tower) to reduce its armor for 15 seconds.

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to activate Satanic for a small window of life steal (which overrides deso) with that setup?